# Regex expression error: "unbalanced parenthesis" but can't find error

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some trouble running the following code which is designed to check for emoticons. I keep getting an error and cannot work out how to fix the issue.

Here is the code:

```
import re

patterns = r"""
    (?:
      [<>]?
      [:;=8]                     # eyes
      [\-o\*\']?                 # optional nose
      [\)\]\(\[dDpP/\:\}\{@\|\\] # mouth      
      |
      [\)\]\(\[dDpP/\:\}\{@\|\\] # mouth
      [\-o\*\']?                 # optional nose
      [:;=8]                     # eyes
      [<>]?
    )
"""

regexes= [re.compile(p) for p in patterns]


text = 'hi there! my name is SimonSchus and here is an emoticon :-)'


for regex in regexes:
    print('Looking for ', regex," in ",(regex.pattern, text))

    if regex.search(text):
        print('found a match!')
    else:
        print('no match')
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
raise error("unbalanced parenthesis")
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Clearly there is an error somewhere with the parentheses/brackets. However, I've escaped everything I can think of with a backslash but still can't work it out. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I feel like the error is in the regex expression itself from a bit of debugging but can't work out what exactly.

Simon.

Credit to Christopher Potts (http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/code-data/happyfuntokenizing.py) from whom I found the emoticon expressions.

Comment: With respect to the expressions -- you've overescaping substantially. I'd suggest testing the subexpressions individually to get them right, being sure that you use `r""` there too.

Comment: Thanks Charles :) I took the expressions from elsewhere so will work through them.

Comment: If you have a a new question, ask it separately (or, better, do a bit more research, thinking and debugging first).

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe. There was no additional question. I was providing an update of my code in case others had a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regexes= [re.compile(p) for p in patterns]
```

...is trying to compile each letter in the string as its own regex. Thus, when `p` is `(`, it expects (and can't find) a closing `)`; likewise for `[` and `]`.

---

Your `patterns` is just one string, not a list of them. Thus:

```
patterns_re = re.compile(patterns)
```

If you wanted a list of regexes, `patterns` would be defined as a list: `patterns=[ ... ]`, not `patterns=r"..."`.

Comment: Thanks :) I amended my code and the error disappeared. Different issue now (the expression aren't matching anything but that is a separate issue that I'll work through myself).